# How many integer solutions does the following equation have?

Tags: combinatorics

I wish to compute the number of integer solutions for the following equation.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n i a_i = n \,\,, a_i \in \{0,\dotsc,n\}
\end{align*}

Comment: Isn't this just the number of *partitions* of $n$, q.v.?

Comment: So, have you had a chance to study up on partitions? or to follow the links in the answer that was posted a couple of days ago? Any comments/questions?

Comment: I am sorry. I saw your answer on Feb 28 and upvoted it as it answered my question. Haven't visited this site since.

Comment: OK. It would have been nice to get some acknowledgement of my comment (votes are anonymous, so I don't have any way to know whether you upvoted it), and Cuttlefish might appreciate some acknowledgement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no closed-form solution, we can describe this problem with the following generating function:

$$g(x) = (1+x+x^2+...)(1+x^2+x^4+...)(1+x^3+x^6+...)\cdots(1+x^n+x^2n+...)$$

$$g(x) = \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{1}{1-x^n}\right)$$

If you want a numerical answer, it will suffice to use any computational tool (Mathematica, SAGE, etc.) to compute the generating function. Unfortunately, this cannot be reduced to a closed-form expression, and so you will have to work with particular cases.

This is closely related to the partition problem, and for more information on partitions, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#

For an alternative solution in summation notation, see http://www.iaeng.org/IJAM/issues_v40/issue_1/IJAM_40_1_01.pdf

This solution is likewise computable with mathematical software, and it presents a more general case than that in your question.

Comment: I think it *is* the partition problem. I don't see any restrictions. OP wants to partition $n$ into at most $n$ parts, each part at most $n$; but *every* partition of $n$ is a partition into at most $n$ parts, each part at most $n$. Anyway, it would be nice to hear from OP.

Comment: Yes, so, $x_1$ is the number of ones in the partition, $x_2$ is the number of twos, and so on. Isn't there a one-one correspondence between solutions of the equation, and partitions of $n$?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: Well, it's *an* appropriate generating function for the question. So is the generating function for unrestricted partitions. And it's not clear that either is the kind of answer OP is looking for (although OP hasn't had much to say...).